# MySQL: delete constraint UNIQUE KEY

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint, unique-key

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( 
//.. 
UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_60349993F97DBD80` (`contrat_parent_id`) 
//.. 
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4384 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci.
```

I try this statement:

> alter table table drop index UNIQ_60349993F97DBD80

But it doesn't work. I try many statements, but, they don't work. 
Can I help me ?

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: @mustaccio The unique key doesn't delete

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: 1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings

Query: alter table contrat drop index UNIQ_60349993F97DBD80

Error Code: 1553
Cannot drop index 'UNIQ_60349993F97DBD80': needed in a foreign key constraint

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0.014 sec

Comment: You have not transcribed the alter table statement correctly the second table should be table1. The error message is self explanatory you need to drop the foreign key before you can drop the unique key.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `ALTER TABLE` from the begging of your statement, and also add the table Name on the end.

```
 drop index UNIQ_60349993F97DBD80 ON table1
```

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-index.html)